# necesito mostrar la fecha por filas y columnas MySQL y el SQL no funciona

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de hacer una consulta de la fecha, por ejemplo:
tengo una columna que se llama Fecha y es de tipo date, en el cual solo almaceno fecha, hora no! pues de esa fecha yo quiero hacer que en columnas me saque los meses, en filas los años registrados y en las celdas me muestre las veces que se repite el mes por ejemplo 2018-05-03, 2018-05-12, ya tendria una fila del año 2018, una columna con el mes de mayo y una celda con 2 registros

```
    SELECT
    YEAR(Fecha) AS AÑO,

    IF( MONTH(fecha)=01, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS ENERO,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=02, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Febrero,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=03, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Marzo,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=04, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Abril,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=05, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Mayo,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=06, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Junio,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=07, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Julio,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=08, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Agosto,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=09, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Septiembre,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=10, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Octubre,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=11, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Nomviembre,
    IF( MONTH(fecha)=12, COUNT(MONTH(fecha)), "0" ) AS Diciembre,

    COUNT(1) as TotalMes

    FROM evidencias GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha);
```

[image: El problema esta que solo en el mes de julio me muestra los 10 registros del año 2018 pero donde señalo con flechas, hay mas registros, como que me guardara los datos solo en el mes de julio]

no comprendo realmente porque se me agregan los datos al mes de julio, si en julio solo tengo 4 registros y tambien hay registros en febrero, marzo y otros mas y lo que esta haciendo ahi es que solo en el mes de julio me esta almacenando todos los registros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, en realidad lo que buscas es sumar 1 cada vez que se cumpla la condición, no contar en el momento en que se cumple. En este caso prueba con `SUM()` en `MySQL`.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Fecha) AS ANO,

    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=01, 1, 0 )) AS Enero,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=02, 1, 0 )) AS Febrero,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=03, 1, 0 )) AS Marzo,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=04, 1, 0 )) AS Abril,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=05, 1, 0 )) AS Mayo,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=06, 1, 0 )) AS Junio,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=07, 1, 0 )) AS Julio,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=08, 1, 0 )) AS Agosto,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=09, 1, 0 )) AS Septiembre,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=10, 1, 0 )) AS Octubre,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=11, 1, 0 )) AS Nomviembre,
    SUM(IF( MONTH(Fecha)=12, 1, 0 )) AS Diciembre,

    COUNT(1) as TotalMes

    FROM evidencias R 
     GROUP BY YEAR(Fecha);
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: estoy totalmente agradecido contigo! 
estoy en deuda contigo! muchisisisisisisisismas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Para eso estamos ;). Si la consideras resuelta márcala como respondida.

Comment: pero no se como! porque la reputacion que tengo aun no me deja. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: dale un +1 a la pregunta @Carmen y el OP que marque la palomita que esta a lado de tu respuesta

Comment: ya lo hice! muchas gracias!

Comment: Un placer. Me gustó el planteamiento para tabular resultados por fecha.

Comment: @Carmen como puedo tener mas privilegios ya entre al chat y no me deja porque necesito mas provilegios y no se como puedo obtener mas

Comment: @Grsn Chml necesitas aumentar tu puntuación, irá aumentando según vayas participando más en la comunidad.